# How does a C compiler convert a constant to binary

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

For the sake of specifics, let's consider GCC compiler, the latest version.

Consider the instruction `int i = 7;`.

In assembly it will be something like

```
MOV 7, R1
```

This will insert the value seven to register R1. The exact instruction may not be important here.

In my understanding, now the compiler will convert the `MOV` instruction to processor specific OPCODE. Then it will allocate a (possibly virtual) register. Then the constant value 7 needs to go in the register.

My question:

**How does the 7 is actually converted to binary?**

Does the compiler actually repeatedly divide by 2 to get the binary representation? (May be afterwards it will convert to HEX, but let's remain on the binary step).

Or, considering that the 7 is written as a character in a text file, is there a clever look up table based technique to convert any string (representing a number) to a binary value?

**If the current GCC compiler uses built in function to convert a string 7 to a binary 0111, then how did the first compiler convert a text based string to a binary value**?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it possibly multiplied by decimal `10` to make the conversion. Consider the decimal value `27` instead. It can be converted to binary by beginning with an accumulator set to `0` and for each incoming digit multiply the accumulator by `10` and add the digit. You don't need a lookup table, nor to build on the back of a previous assembler or compiler. But what do you mean by "afterwards convert to hex"? These number bases are for string formatting so that humans can read them.

Comment: I assumed there might be a need to convert to an HEX value, but if it is not important for the actual text to binary algorithm, then we can ignore that part. Thank you.

Comment: A single digit character can be converted to its numerical value by subtracting `'0'`. So in your case, the character  `'7'` with `'7' - '0'` applied becomes the value `7`.

Comment: Is that a character 0 represented by the single quote?

Comment: This is a `'character'` and this is a `value`.

Comment: In ASCII the `'7'` is `0x37`. But there is no need to hard code that. So your code becomes portable because the encoding of digits `'0'` to `'9'` is usually guaranteed to be consecutive. That's why we tell the assembler/compiler to subtract `'0'` and not `0x30`.

Comment: I understand.  Thank you so much for your patience.  I will none the less keep the q open, just in case I learn about other algorithms from other answers

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how `atoi` works.  It works by looking at each character in turn, converting that character value into the value of that digit, multiplying the existing sum by 10, and adding the new digit value.  Poof!  It decodes a base 10 integer, producing a binary result.  It's just a few lines of very simple code.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the 7 is actually converted to binary?

First of all, there's a distinction between the binary base 2 number format and what professional programmers call "a binary executable", meaning generated machine code and most often expressed in hex for convenience. Addressing the latter meaning:

Disassemble with binaries (for example at https://godbolt.org/) and see for yourself

```
int main (void)
{
  int i = 7;
  return i;
}
```

Does indeed get translated to something like

```
mov    eax,0x7
ret
```

Translated to binary op codes:

```
B8 07 00 00 00
C3
```

Where B8 = `mov eax`, B9 = `mov ecx` and so on. The 7 is translated into `07 00 00 00` since `mov` expects 4 bytes and this is a little endian CPU.

And this is the point where the compiler/linker stops caring. The code was generated according to the CPU's ABI (Application Binary Interface) and how to deal with this machine code from here on is up to the CPU.

As for how this makes it into the hardware in the actual form of base 2 binary... it's already in that form. Everything we see in a PC is a translated convenience for the human users, who have an easier time reading decimal or hex than raw binary.

Comment: Yes,but how is the 7 actually converted to  07 00 00 00? Did the compiler run something like divide by 2 repeatedly? or did it recognize the character 7, and then subtracted the ASCII code for 0 from it, then got the 0111, binary for 7 ? If it were in a text file, then it would have been the ascii code for 7, and not the binary encoding for 7 the processor would need to handle it as a number.

Comment: @Sean Source files are text so it simply translates text to integers. A compiler is an intricate text parser, among other things.

Comment: Ok, so which algorithms are usually used for text to integer, or may be even float parsing? the AtoI algorithm mentioned above? Does the compiler actually run such algorithms during its compilation cycle? Thank you.

Comment: @Sean How to cover text to integers is usually covered by any decent C programming book.

Comment: Yes, the AtoI algorithm. My question is, the gcc compiler, behind the scene, is really running this algorithm?

Comment: @Sean I don't know, nor do I care. Download the source from Github and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`If the current GCC compiler uses built in function to convert a string 7 to a binary 0111, then how did the first compiler convert a text based string to a binary value?` This is egg chicken problem but to simply put these compilers are created step by step and at some point the compiler is written in its language such that c compiler is written by c etc.
Before to answer your question we should define what we mean by "compilation" or what compiler does. to simply put this compilation is a pipeline. Takes your high level code does some operations and generates an assembly code(specific to machine) and machine defined assembler takes your assembly code and converts it into a binary object file.
At the compiler level all they do is to create corresponding assembly format in a text file.
[image]

and assembler is another program that takes this `text` file and converts it into "binary" format. 
 Assembler can be also written by c language here we also need a mapping i.e movl->(0000110101110...) but this one is binary not ascii. and we need to write this binary into a file as-is. 
Converting numbers into binary format is also redundant because numbers are already in binary form when they are loaded into memory.

 the question is how they are converted/placed in to memory is a problem of the loader program of the operating system which exceeds my knowledge.

Comment: But the number 7 be already in binary form, representing a character in the text file containing the source code  instead of being in a form representing an integer, no?

Comment: I'm not following what you say but in an object file, everything is binary, so it consist of only 0s and 1s. viewing that files by using some editors might be tricky. Considering that, the values(text numbers) must already be identified and transferred to binary forms either by compiler itself or the assembler program. there're some methods of doing this constantly division is only one of them.

Comment: But before you get the object file,  you have a text file with the source code. The source code is in ascii. Here, you have 110111 for the character `'7'` . That is the ascii code. You need to convert it to `0111`  so that it is now in integer. How does this translation ACTUALLY work?